# MS Project 2010 freezes when trying to import data from Excel file

Tags: excel, vba, ms-project

For lots of years now I've been using a macro which imports data from a .xls file to MS Project. The thing is that for unknown reasons it only works on MS Project 2003. When I try running it on MS Project 2010 the moment before Import process finishes MS Project just freezes and nothing happens after that.

What is even more strange is that even without the macro (if I try to import the data manually using File -> Open -> ...) it still doesn't work, whereas in MS Project 2003 both ways work fine.

It seems to me as if the problem isn't connected to VBA at all but I am gonna post the macro here so you guys could see it anyway.

Here is some further information which I think might be important:

1. I'm using a custom mpp template.
2. I'm using a custom import map.
3. I tried using method FileOpenEx and it still doesn't work.
4. The .xls file I'm trying to import has three sheets for Task, Ressource and Assigment.
5. I tried saving the file as .xlsx since I'm using a newer version of Project but this didn't change anything.
6. I think it fails just at the end cause if i try to do it manually I can see how work is shown on the timeline graph next to the table in MS Project.

And here is the macro:

```
Dim filename As String

FileNew Template:="", FileNewWorkpane:=True

FileOpen Name:="PATH TO THE TEMPLATE FILE", _
    ReadOnly:=False

FileOpen Name:="PATH TO FILE TO IMPORT", _
    ReadOnly:=False, map:="MY CUSTOM MAPNAME"

filename = "C:\Imported.mpp"

Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If fs.FileExists(namedoc) Then

    Dim OldName, NewName
    
    nomfile = 1
    
    OldName = filename: NewName = "C:\Imported old Copy 1.mpp"
    
    While fs.FileExists(NewName)
    
        nomfile = nomfile + 1
        
        NewName = "C:\Imported old Copy " & nomfile & ".mpp"
    
    Wend
    
    Name OldName As NewName

End If
    
FileSaveAs Name:="C:\Imported.mpp", FormatID:="MSProject.MPP"
```

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try putting the data in a csv file and see if that is accepted in MS Project 2010.

Comment: @SolarMike thanks for the suggestion, but isn't .csv file for one-sheet situations only? I have three sheets in my .xls file and I don't know how to combine them all in a single one

Comment: So do 3 separate ones - if that works then you can check out other options. A process of elimination to find out what works may help you solve it.

Comment: Since this issue is with the application and not vba, I suggest you post this to the [Project Management](https://pm.stackexchange.com) site where you'll find more Project experts.

Comment: I also suggest that you break up the import and start with creating a new file with the resources, then merge in the tasks, then merge in the assignments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the custom fields I was using. I had four `Outline_Code` columns used for storing some text information.

I replaced them with four Text fields (Text1, Text2, Text3, Text4) and now the data is imported!